# Как организовать автоматическую рассылку на почту клиентам через язык C# .Net Framework

Tags: c#, .net, smtp

Вот код который формирует сообщение и отправляет его.

```
 using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
                        {
                            mail.From = new MailAddress(MyEmail);

                            mail.To.Add(person.Email);

                            mail.Subject = subject;

                            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

                            mail.Body = person.TextMessage;

                            using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(smtpAddress, port_number))
                            {
                                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(MyEmail, MyPassword);

                                //smtp.EnableSsl = enable_ssl;

                                smtp.Send(mail);
                            }


                        }
```

Проблема в том что введя свою почту от имени которой осуществляется отправка и пароль к ней, мой google account предотвращает попытку входа с незнакомого устройства. Как это исправить? В итоге прилетает Exception "Серверу SMTP требовалось защищенное соединение, или подлинность клиента не была установлена. Отклик сервера: 5.7.0 Authentication Required".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26709761/6468198

Comment: Пожалуйста, отформатируйте код с нормальными отступами.

Comment: и в самом гугл аккаунте надо разрешить отправку через сторонние программы и EnableSsl = true для гугла

Answer (score 0):

Гугл в этом плане очень строг, от слова совсем.

Мой совет - это юзайте собственную почту.

Но так-же у меня есть готовый код для отправки сообщений через mail.ru
Вот код для отправки сообщений из mail.ru:

```
                        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.ru", 25);

                        mail.From = new MailAddress("ПАРОЛЬ");
                        mail.To.Add("ПОЧТА ДЛЯ ОТПРАВКИ");
                        mail.Subject = "ТЕМА СООБЩЕНИЯ";
                        mail.Body = "ТЕКСТ СООБЩЕНИЯ";


                        SmtpServer.Credentials = (ICredentialsByHost)new NetworkCredential("ПАРОЛЬ ОТПРАВИТЕЛЯ", "ЕМАИЛ ОТПРАВИТЕЛЯ");

                        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
                        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
                            delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
                            { return true; };


                        SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```